# Magento2 shop with 2 store views, each view displays same category different

Tags: magento2, category, store-view, language, multiple

I have 2 store views (english and german) associated with 1 store. I want the same Category called 'Kaschmir' to be displayed differently on both store views
-> english store view 'Kashmir'
-> german store view 'Kaschmir'

Is that possible ?

Comment: Which is your Magento 2 version?

Comment: The Version is 2.1.1

Comment: Yes, that's possible. In Magento category name can be set for store view scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set the category name for store view scope. Select the appropriate store view:

[image]